# No suitable conversion function

Tags: c++, function, error-handling, menu

I am currently working on a menu that, when the user inputs the corresponding number, the menu will connect and use that function. These functions are arithmetic (add, subtract, multiply, and divide). However every time I run the program I get this error
"No suitable conversion function from "std::is_function<void()>" to "void(*)()" exits

```
void Byte::addMenu(const char* description, std::is_function<void()> f) {
    if (count < MAXCOUNT) {
        this->mi[count].func = f; 
        strcpy_s(this->mi[count].descript, description);
        count++;
    }

}
```

I tried to switch the second parameter to

```
void Byte::addMenu(const char* description,void(Byte::*f)(int)).
```

However I received the same error.

Here is an update version of the were I attempted to use the addMenu function

Header file

```
#pragma once    
#ifndef MATH
#define MATH

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


using std::string;
using std::vector;

//Menu Code
const int MAXCOUNT = 30;

struct menuItem {
    void(*func)();
    char descript[30];
};
class Math {
private:
    //Menu Code
    int count = 0;
    menuItem mi[MAXCOUNT] = {};
    void runSelection();
public:
    void addMenu(const char* description, void(Math::* f)(int));
    void runMenu();
    void Exit();
    int add(); 
};

#endif // !MATH
```

Math.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Math.h"

using namespace std;

void Math::addMenu(const char* description, void(Math::* f)(int)) {
    if (count < MAXCOUNT) {
        this->mi[count].func = f;
        strcpy_s(this->mi[count].descript, description);
        count++;
    }
}

void Math::runMenu(){ 
    for (;;) {
        system("CLS");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            cout << this->mi[i].descript << endl;
    }
    runSelection();
}

void Math::runSelection() {
    int select;
    cin >> select;
    if (select <= count) {
        this->mi[select - 1].func();
    }
}

void Math::Exit() {
    char c;
    cout << "GoodBye! " << endl;
    exit(0);
}

 int Math::add() {
    int val1, val2;
    cout << "Enter two values to add" << endl;
    cin >> val1 >> val2;
    int sum = val1 + val2;
    cout << "The sum of the two numbers is" << sum << endl;

    return sum; 
}
```

Main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Math.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Math m;

    m.addMenu("1.add two values", &Math::add);
    m.addMenu("2.Exit", &Math::Exit);

    m.runMenu();
}
```

I am still receiving the  compilation error for the addMenu function().

```
'=': cannot convert from 'void(_cdecl Math::*)(int)' to 'void(_cdecl*)(void)'
```

Comment: The types of `f` and `this->mi[count].func` are different. Make them the same type?

Comment: So the addMenu would hold a decryption of the arithmetic function followed by the function which is classified as an int type function. If I were to change the function type then the arithmetic function would not work as it only receives integers/whole numbers   @user12002570

Comment: Seems like you want `std::function<void()> f`, i.e. `function` not `is_function`. `std::function` is a type representing a function, `std::is_function` is a template which tests if a type is a function. Confusing maybe, but these are two totally different things.

Comment: It seems like you are getting various types mixed up. Really for a full solution you need to post the definition of `func`, examples of how `func` is being used and examples of how `addMenu` is being called. In other words a [mre].

Comment: A side note: _"every time I run the program I get this error"_ - you actually get a compilation error. A C++ program can run only after it passes the compilation phase (and an executable is built).

Comment: @StevenOsi Kindly provide a [mcve]

Comment: @john and  I have edited the code to show a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @StevenOsi The problem is that a function pointer `void(*)()` is completely different from a member function pointer `void (C::*)()`. In fact, **member function pointers are not actually pointers despite their name.**

Comment: @user12002570 so should I not use a pointer in this scenario for the addMenu function?

Comment: @StevenOsi Just change `void(*func)();` to `void (Math::*func)();` See [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K9oMszYh9) where I did this and it compiles.

Comment: @StevenOsi See the comment in [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K9oMszYh9) that shows the change I made.

Comment: @user12002570 unfortunately when I implemented the change that you recommeneded  I received more compilation errors.

Comment: @StevenOsi Yes, you'll have to figure out to solve those errors. I would recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that explains these basic things.

Comment: @StevenOsi Get the design right first, fix the compiler errors afterwards. Don't be tempted to change your design, if you think it is right, just because of compiler errors. As to the new compiler errors I'm guessing `this->mi[select - 1].func();` should be changed to `(this->*mi[select - 1].func)();`. You need to research how pointers to member functions work, in particular the `->*` operator that allows you to call a pointer to member function.

Comment: @StevenOsi But going back to your design I can see no reason why `Add` and `Exit` must be member functions. Neither function uses the `Math` class at all. The code would be easier if you just made them regular functions. Like I said, think about the design first, get it right, and stick with in, then write the code. So your first decision is whether you really want `Add` and `Exit` to be member functions or not. Decide that then write the code accordingly.

Comment: @john Thank you John. I took a few a day to just research and figure it out (which I did). The design, although a bit messy, was close enough to what my prof. wanted. If not then hot dog